# If statement based on current "view"

Tags: android

So in my I app I work with fragments so the "backpress" is not working correctly. What I want to do is if the screen shows my "Mainactivity" and I press the "backbutton" on the phone I want to exit the application.

Currently I have this code:

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction();
    fm.popBackStack();

}
```

But I need to do something like this:

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if("CurrentView" == "MainActivity") {
    app.close() 
    }else{
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction();
    fm.popBackStack();
}

}
```

But yea ofc this wont work becuase its not real code. I hope you can get what I mean and help me with a solution.

Comment: means if you are showing fragment then it should pop fragment and if the activity is showing you want to close the application

Comment: In Fragment within use Activity class, that is best practice of android. otherwise u wont get proper solutions.

Comment: can you show your code how you are adding fragment

Comment: are you calling addToBackStack() method when you add your fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Use instanceOf

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     if(this instanceof Activity_name) 
     {
         app.close() 
     }
   else{
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction();
fm.popBackStack();
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for but. Instead of `app.close()` I used `System.exit(0)`

Comment: I thought this was the right way of doing it but the condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

That is Automaticly done by the fragment manager. If the fragment is in back stack it will first pop on the back key, then on another back key the app will close it self if there is no more fragments left. Only thing you need to do is add that fragment to the back stack when you are adding it to the fragment transaction.

Comment: But when I start the application and press back its open my map. So I thought a simple solution would be to add a if statement.